# Stix Two Math keeps rewriting the cache with lualatex

Tags: luatex, latexmk, stix

Tex Live version: `TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020)`

This MWE is used throughout:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Schola}[Scale=0.97]
\setmathfont{Tex Gyre Schola Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmathfont[range={\int,\iint}]{Stix Two Math}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmonofont{inconsolatan}[Scale=MatchLowercase,StylisticSet={1,3}]

\begin{document}

\section*{The first section}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog's back.
\begin{equation}
  x=\alpha + \beta
\end{equation}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog's back.

\verb!The quick brown fox jumps \emph{emphasized} over the lazy dog's back.!

\end{document}
```

It passes lualatex without any issues, and gives a .pdf as expected.

My problem has to do with the font cache, `...texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic-dev/fonts/otl`. This is a listing of the font cache before running my MWE:

```
Created at 2020-08-31 16:30 with ls -ltr, i.e. latest file last.
    .
    .
    .
-rw-rw-r-- 1 leif leif  337751 2020-08-29 14:36 texgyreschola-regular.lua
-rw-rw-r-- 1 leif leif  204144 2020-08-29 14:36 texgyreschola-regular.luc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 leif leif  333538 2020-08-29 14:36 texgyreschola-bolditalic.lua
-rw-rw-r-- 1 leif leif  198037 2020-08-29 14:36 texgyreschola-bolditalic.luc
    .
    .
    .
-rw-rw-r-- 1 leif leif  722234 2020-08-30 12:47 stix2text-regular.lua
-rw-rw-r-- 1 leif leif  466687 2020-08-30 12:47 stix2text-regular.luc
    .
    .
-rw-rw-r-- 1 leif leif  764569 2020-08-30 12:47 stix2text-italic.lua
-rw-rw-r-- 1 leif leif  477285 2020-08-30 12:47 stix2text-italic.luc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 leif leif 1042702 2020-08-31 15:03 stix2math.lua
-rw-rw-r-- 1 leif leif  628077 2020-08-31 15:03 stix2math.luc
```

After running the MWE the cache looks like

```
Created at 2020-08-31 16:44 with ls -ltr, i.e. latest file last.
    .
    .
    .
-rw-rw-r-- 1 leif leif  764569 2020-08-30 12:47 stix2text-italic.lua
-rw-rw-r-- 1 leif leif  477285 2020-08-30 12:47 stix2text-italic.luc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 leif leif 1042702 2020-08-31 16:44 stix2math.lua
-rw-rw-r-- 1 leif leif  628077 2020-08-31 16:44 stix2math.luc
```

As you can see all the other entries are untouched, but the two files for `stix2math` have been rewritten.

Why do I complain, you may ask. After all, lualatex only rewrites about 2MB, which takes just a few seconds on my machine. The reason is that I use `latexmk` to handle my document, and the files in the cache are considered when `latexmk` decides if another run is necessary. Since the files in the cache are changed for each run, `latexmk` will never consider the work done, but will continue until maximum number of runs is reached.

So my questions are

- Is there a way to get `lualatex` to not rewrite the cache files?

or

- Is there a way to get `latexmk` to ignore the font cache files when deciding if another run is necessary?

**Edit** I did a diff of stix2math.lua between two runs of `lualatex <file>`, and it begins as

```
--- before.lua  2020-08-31 18:10:56.636561526 +0200
+++ after.lua   2020-08-31 18:11:29.024059824 +0200
@@ -658,9 +658,9 @@
    ["math"]={
     ["accent"]=440,
     ["kerns"]={
-     ["bottomleft"]=20,
-     ["bottomright"]=19,
-     ["topright"]=19,
+     ["bottomleft"]=19,
+     ["bottomright"]=20,
+     ["topright"]=20,
     },
    },
    ["name"]="M",
@@ -22748,7 +22748,7 @@
        ["kern"]=100,
       },
      },
-     ["topright"]=20,
+     ["topright"]=19,
     },
    },
    ["unicode"]=119813,
```

and then it continues like this with changes of typically one unit in many items throughout.

Comment: If you don't use latexmk but directly lualatex, are then the font files recreated too?

Comment: Yes, I used lualatex directly between the two listings.

Comment: can you make a diff of the two lua-files? Did anything change?

Comment: Something did change, to my surprise, verified with md5sum. I'll try to do a proper diff.

Comment: The beginning of the diff is in my edited question.

Comment: hm, looks like random rounding.  What is the version of your luaotfload?

Comment: Luaotfload: "v3.14/2020-05-06" , Tex Live version: TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020)

Comment: I can not reproduce it, but I'm on windows and I use the development version. Open an issue https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues, perhaps Marcel has an idea.

Comment: Will do. Thanks.

Comment: @LeifLund Please include the full diff in the issue and the diff after running LuaTeX again in the issue.

Comment: I'm also unable to reproduce the problem.  This is on an up-to-date TeXLive 2020 on macOS.  On the first run of lualatex, the stix2math.lua and stix2math.luc files were written.  Thereafter they did not change and weren't rewritten. Once the cache files were created, latexmk (with the -pdflua option) only ran lualatex once.

Comment: To get latexmk to ignore changes in the cache files mentioned, put the line `$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'lua'} = $hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'luc'} = '';` in a latexmkrc file. That configuration has the unfortunate side effect of telling latexmk to ignore all changes in all those files that have extension lua or luc. That's obviously very undesirable, so this is obviously only a temporary fix to evade a bug until it is fixed. There's no easy way to be more selective on the files that latexmk ignores changes to.

Comment: To anyone reading this far: I actually did open an issue at GitHub: [https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/166](https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/166). There is some interesting discussions and conclusions there.